# How to convert CoinMarketCap from text into number (saying it cannot be coerced)

Tags: google-sheets-formula, coinmarketcap

This is code I am using

=IMPORTXML("https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/"&D6,"//div[contains(@class,'priceValue')]")

D6 being the name of the crytpocurrency used in the url

This shows the price as text

I click on an E6 and type =D6 and get the price. I then type in F6*2 (for example) and get the following message: Function MULTIPLY parameter 1 expects number values. But '$34,105.30' is a text and cannot be coerced to a number.

I am new to this and just want an easy way to multiply/divide the data produced from CMC.

I'd appreciate any help with this (explained to me like a 4 year old)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

imagine you have a keyboard hooked up to the calculator and you type in:

```
2 + seven =
```

the calculator won't sum it coz it does not understand the concept of words. same applies to your case too:

```
$34,105.30
```

is text and to turn it into number you need to remove

```
$,
```

so try:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(IMPORTXML("https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/"&D6,
 "//div[contains(@class,'priceValue')]"), "[\$,]", )*1
```